# CMake flag getting stuck

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

While giving the cmake command I am using the flag "`-DWITH_DAY=1`" option as the flag.
This flag is available in the code and wokrs fine.
But when I want to build other ibrary using the same code but without this flag I need to erase the definition of this flag because in my code I have statements like 
"`if(NOT DEFINED WITH_DAY)`"
But when I do a cmake without this flag the `WITH_DAY` still remains defined! and hence my build fails.
It only works if I remove the `CMakeCache.txt` file or the entire build directory.

I want is to be disabled if I do not specify it in the command line.

Comment: Why do not use a BOOL variable you can manage through ccmake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run `cmake -U WITH_DAY .` before building other library. It's because CMake saves `WITH_DAY`'s value in the cache (`CMakeCache.txt`).

Alternatively, as @Caduchon has mentioned, you can make `WITH_DAY` an [option](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aoption) and change your if statement to just

```
if(WITH_DAY)
```